# mySQL/Server performance check.. 1000 basic update queries = 57 seconds on a QuadCore i7 rig.. GOod or bad?

Tags: mysql, performance, sql-update

just wanted to check what you guys think of this performance...

i have an Intel i7 ivybridge quad, 16GB DDR3 RAM, 7200RPM Drives for the server/mysql drive etc...

i ran a simple update on 1000 records:
$q2 = "UPDATE msg_inbox SET receivedtime='$epochTime' WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1 ";

granted that each of this is fired based on a current foreach loop (on each id returned).. 
but if i comment this update query out, the page takes .0300 seconds to load all 1000 records..

but w/ the update query , it lags to 57seconds before the page completely done...i checked using PHP microtime.

Is this normal and as expected performance or is there something wrong here? (perhaps my machine)

regards

TABLE INFORMATION:
Definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `msg_inbox` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sender` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `sender_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `receiver` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `receiver_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `msg` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `senttime` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `receivedtime` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `operator` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `device_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `msgtype` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `read_by` varchar(20) NOT NULL COMMENT 'marks a message to be read or unread with ID of who read it',
  `folder_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `owner` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `prefix` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `raw_gwdata` text,
  `stat` enum('normal','important','deleted') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'normal',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8528 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

There are total of 7887 rows in the table at the moment..

Comment: Sounds pretty slow, but to even attempt to try to explain why, you'll need to add more info, for example how many rows the table has/what indexes there are. Also, getting 1000 id's from the database just to pass them back sounds like it may be a good use of a join to eliminate entirely.

Comment: 57 seconds for updating 1000 items on modern hardware with lots of memory is waaay too slow - something else is going on. However, this question cannot be answered objectively.

Comment: What is the datatype of id? `WHERE id='$id' `

Comment: Can you put up the table definition? 57 seconds for only 1000 updates sounds horrendously slow. But if id is a non indexed field and there are lots of records on that table then it would not be surprising.

Comment: thank you guys for the comments.. it does give me an idea of what to expect.. 

to answer some of the questions.. at the moment, yes the id's are indexed. integer 11 ..  

I have updated my post to contain more table information..

@JoachimIsaksson, i dont see any other way to optimize the sql updates other than to do it 1 by 1.. it's a routine to update all the "timestamps" of the messages , and each message will have its own time.. there's no magic avaialble for this, it's gotta be 1 at a time. .. so i think

Comment: @BrownChiLD What query is returning the id's to begin with?

Answer (score 1):

Guessing that id column is indexed... I would say that you need to look at you MySql connection limit, [HERE](http://major.io/2007/01/24/increase-mysql-connection-limit/).

I would say your machine and query is fine and that you need to take a careful look at you mysql / php configuration.

PS: I have seen dual cores with 4 gig ram do a 1000 inserts in less than 30 seconds.

Comment: thank you for this insight. i will look into it. thank you also for confirmation on better results on slower machines.. it does trigger me to setup the whole thing, EXACTLY AS IT IS, on a different machine. perhaps my laptop , and see how it fares there.. just to rule out other possible reasons/causes..

re connection limit, i just did  a quick read, and nope i dont think this is it coz im the only one using this server (DEV SERVER) and i dont think i would've exhausted the connection limits.. unless each SQL UPDATE call is 1 connection thread, w/c i doubt.

Comment: Well that was something specific that I had an issue once, it was set to a ridiculous 10. You actually sparked my interest with this and I ran a test on my dev machine (I5 8gig 7200rpm) which has a straight out of the box mysql server. I updated a 300 000 + table on an index id a varchar(32) field and it took 57 seconds. So post your  configuration when you done and we run the test again?

Comment: wow, i am hella off .. shucks.. im gona setup some tests for this then.. 1st, will try exact config on different machine.. (rule out server installation /config issues or hardware issues) .. then go from there. will post back soon

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution to speed things up is to batch up your UPDATES. Id is unique, and if you are only going to ever update existing ids (and not going to try and update an id that doesn't already exist) then you can use an INSERT.....ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE type query.

The advantage of this is that you can update hundreds of rows with the new values in a single statement, and this is pretty quick.

When doing this I sometimes use a class to keep track of the records, and it can sort out when to do an insert.

An example (using php) follows (not directly tested so maybe the odd typo):-

```
<?php

$InsertObject = new generic_insert($db_object, 'msg_inbox', array('id', 'receivedtime'), 1000);

foreach ($DetailsArray AS $DetailItem)
{
    InsertObject->InsertItem("($DetailItem[id], $DetailItem[receivedtime])");
}

unset($InsertObject);

class generic_insert
{
    var $db;
    var $InsertArray = array();
    var $TableName = '';
    var $InsertBatchSize = 1000;
    var $UpdateClause = '';
    function __CONSTRUCT($db, $TableName, $ColumnArray, $InsertBatchSize = 1000)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
        $this->TableName = $TableName;
        $this->ColumnArray = $ColumnArray;
        $this->InsertBatchSize = $InsertBatchSize;

        foreach (array_slice($this->ColumnArray, 1) AS $ColumnItem)
        {
            $UpdateArray = "$ColumnItem=VALUES($ColumnItem)";
        }
        if (count($UpdateArray) > 0)
        {
            $this->UpdateClause = " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE SET ".implode(',', $UpdateArray);
        }
    }
    function __DESTRUCT()
    {
        if (count($this->InsertArray) > 0)
        {
            $this->PerformInsert();
        }
    }

    public function InsertItem($InItem)
    {
        $this->InsertArray[] = $InItem;
        if (count($this->InsertArray) > $this->InsertBatchSize)
        {
            $this->PerformInsert();
        }
    }

    private function PerformInsert()
    {
        $query = "INSERT INTO ".$this->TableName." (`".implode('`, `', $this->ColumnArray)."`) VALUES ".implode(",", $this->InsertArray)." ".$this->UpdateClause;
        $stmtId = $this->db->query($query);
        if ($stmtId === false)
        {
            die("Insert To ".$this->TableName." Failed - ".$this->db->error());
        }
        else
        {
            $this->db->free_result($stmtId);
        }
        $this->InsertArray = array();
    }
}

?>
```

The class takes a few parameters, including the database object, table name, an array of the column names (the first is assumed to be the primary key) and the max number of updates to be done at once (in this case 1000). It should be fairly generic.